# WebServices never returned data back

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have a web services app written in C# that takes an array of data as the input and returns also an array of data as the output. I also wrote a client application that uses this web services app.

One of my remote clients had an issue that the client app hung after it was started. They used an array of about 4k records. I ran the same records both internally and with an outside connection on my machine, they all worked fine. I then VPNed to the client's machine and found that the web services finished processing all the records, but none of the records was returned back to the client app, which caused client app to hang. There was no error at all on either the web services or the client side.

My guess was that the connection between the client app and the web services was lost when the web services was still processing the records. Therefore, I broke the input array into a block of 1k records, so every time the client app only sends a max of 1k records to the web services. I then was getting inconsistent behavior, as the client app sometimes worked but sometimes didn't.

I've tried everything I could think of. Could someone help me on this issue please??? Thanks!!!!

Comment: Is this an asmx or a wcf web service?

Comment: it is asmx.

If it is network timeout, shouldn't there be an exception thrown?

Answer (score -1):

If this is a WCF service have you checked the app.config files for both the client and the server side application to ensure that you have set the maxArraySize and maxReader quota sizes for WCF messages? Make sure also that the two quotas are the same both sides.

Comment: OK John, but a bit harsh as a down-vote as it was only a comment providing that information at the time, perhaps I should have read them all, but it should have been included in the main question. At least you have now added asmx to the tags to improve the visibility of this. I'd recommend editing the question also to read 'I have an asmx web service'.